# mongoose push nested subdocument array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i need to push data in nested subdocument array:

**this is my Json:**

```
[
  {
    _id: "56cbe9727bab33a413216dd4",
    company_name: "Star",
    __v: 0,
    created_at: "2016-02-23T05:09:06.754Z",
    plan: [
            {
            plan_name: "Mediclassic",
            plan_type: "Individual",
            _id: "56cbe9727bab33a413216dd5",
            created_at: "2016-02-23T05:09:06.756Z",
            rate_card: [
                          {
                            zone: "zone-2",
                            suminsured: 150000,
                            premium: 2874,
                            size: "1A",
                            _id: "56cbe9727bab33a413216dd6",
                            benefits: {
                            hospitals: true,
                            copay: true,
                            cashless_hospital: true,
                            existing_disease_cover: true
                            },
                            age: {
                            min: "5M",
                            max: 35
                            }
                          }
                        ]
            }
          ]
  }
]
```

I need to push my data in **rate_card**, i have tried something but its not working

below is my code:

**AngularController.js**

```
$scope.RateCardCreateAction = function(){
    $scope.params = $routeParams.id;
    console.log($scope.insurance.plan.rate_card);
    $http.put('/auth/insurance-list/plan/new/rate_card/' + $scope.params, $scope.insurance.plan.rate_card).success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        refresh();
    });
};
```

**mainRoutes.js**

// New Rate Card

```
router.put('/secure/insurance-list/plan/new/rate_card/:id', function(req, res){
var id = req.params.id;
Insurance.update({'plan._id':id}, {$push : 
    { 
        'rate_card' : {
            'zone' : req.body.zone,
            'suminsured' : req.body.suminsured,
            'premium' : req.body.premium,
            'size' : req.body.size, 
            'age' : {
                        'min' : req.body.age.min, 
                        'max' : req.body.age.max
                    },
            'benefits' : {
                            'hospitals' : req.body.benefits.hospitals,
                            'cashless_hospital' : req.body.benefits.cashless_hospital,
                            'copay' : req.body.benefits.copay,
                            'existing_disease_cover' : req.body.benefits.existing_disease_cover
                        }

            }   
    }
}, {upsert: true}, function(err, docs){
res.json(docs);
console.log(docs);
});
```

});

Here i need to push data to rate_card, but data is not storing in subdocument array, here am getting plan id and trying to push but is not working

in server response am getting this `{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }`

Comment: Do you need to select which company your are updating first?  It seems like you're trying to update the plan before knowing which document you're on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, i hope this will help you

```
router.put('/secure/insurance-list/plan/new/rate_card/:id/:id2', function(req, res){
        var id = req.params.id;
        var id2 = req.params.id2;
        Insurance.update({_id:id, 'plan._id':id2}, {$push : 
            {'plan.$.rate_card' : req.body}
        }, {upsert: true}, function(err, docs){
        res.json(docs);
        console.log(docs);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Heyy I have encountered the similar problem but unable to solve it trying the above thing. I posted by problem on this stackoverflow please help me if you can. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66027692/need-to-push-data-in-nested-subdocument-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66027692/need-to-push-data-in-nested-subdocument-array)

Answer (score 0):

If somehow your inserted value is not present then it would be great to use $addToSet.

```
var updateArr = {
  'roomUsers':{
     userId:req.session.userInfo._id,
     requestDate:Date.now(),
     status:1
  }
};

roomInfo.findOneAndUpdate({_id:roomId}, {$addToSet:updateArr}, (err, result) => {

if (!err && result) {
  res.send({
     status:true
  });
}
 else{
    res.send({
      status:false
    });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it done using below update query:

```
db.insurance.updateOne(
{
    _id: ObjectId('60659595afcb710627e3fad7')
},
{
    $push: {
        "plan.$[element].rate_card": {
            $each: [
                { _id: ObjectId('6062bd90c5a1d66fdd2c91bc'), premium: 2874, size: "1A" },
                { _id: ObjectId('6062bd90c5a1d66fdd2c91bc'), premium: 2874, size: "1A" }]
        }
    }
},
{
    arrayFilters: [{ "element._id": ObjectId('6065a35ee1e5f1153504e861') }]
}
);
```

In `$each` you need to add your array of object.
`element._id` is your subdocument id (above case is `plan _id`).